# Is the Kiddush required to be in a separate house / building?

Tags: purim-torah-in-jest

I noticed that the smell of warming kugel and chulent on Shabbat disturbs people's kavanah during davening. I can tell from these actions:

- People stare at the announcements handout to see who sponsored the Kiddush
- They talk to each other about what's being served
- A few people sneak to the Kiddush room during haftarah or the Rav's drash for a taste or, at least, a peak
- During the rav's drash, he has to mention the Kiddush sponsors and that there's a lavish Kiddush
- Sometimes, the kids are asked to rush *Anim Z'miros* so that they can get to the Kiddush faster
- Hardly anyone waits for the rabbi to make Kiddush for everyone (Very disrespectful, BTW)

Since the smell of the kugel and chulent seems more likely to trigger these reactions (they may think about the Kiddush even w/o the smell, but the smell makes it more likely) and lose their kavanah, is there a requirement that the Kiddush be in a different building so that the smell can't be notice during davening?

## This question is [Purim Torah](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Purim_Torah) and is not intended to be taken completely seriously. See the [Purim Torah policy](http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/797/).#

Comment: This might be worth a real question -- is it a problem to have the kiddush "smellable" during davening?

Comment: @Cnsersmoit - I may eventually turn it into a real question.

Answer (score 2):

My Shul has instituted just such a policy! Since we must be mikaddesh the kiddush, it must currently be chol (before we make kiddush). We are commanded to be mavdil bein kodesh lachol, which means we must separate the pre-kiddush food into a different house, since we consider the entire beis haknesses to be a mikdash me'at, and ***not a mikdash meat.***

I must question, however, whether we consider the smell of the food itself to be chol. Chazal tell us that the sense of re'ach is the only remaining purely ruchani sense left. Since shabbos food is on a greater madregah than weekday food, it may be entirely appropriate to utilize the ruchnius of it's smell before kiddush, provided that one make a proper bracha!

Comment: +1 for the "mikdash meat"! Does your shul have the Kiddush I a separate building BTW. I doubt that b/c of a policy..

Comment: @danf we do in fact have kiddush separately in our Shul. It was deliberately built without a social hall in order to keep it cleaner. Kiddush is next door in what used to be the old Shul.

Comment: Smart move, esp. for cleanliness. Though, it seems that it may require a bit more work for the cleaning crew.